# How can I add an image at top border using /paperwidth in just one specific page?

Tags: spacing, graphics, memoir, wide-image

I need to put one image at top of one page that spans through all paperwidth, I've tried the next command in `memoir`:

```
\newcommand{\adjustimg}{
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage\hspace*{\dimexpr\evensidemargin-\oddsidemargin}\else\hspace*{-\dimexpr\evensidemargin-\oddsidemargin}\fi}

\newcommand{\centerimg}[2][width=\textwidth]{\makebox[\textwidth]{\adjustimg\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}

\mbox{} \par
\vspace*{-3.6cm}\noindent\centerimg[width=\paperwidth]{*myimage*}
```

The problem here is that it always gets me a white side line like this one:

[image]

Could yo help me? If there are other solutions it would be great.

Comment: You need a `%` on the first line of the definition of `\adjustimg`. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Comment: @Werner thank you so much! it works :) I'll read that information.